# How do I validate user input in a loop?

Tags: powershell

I'm a student and I need to write a script in Powershell ISE that will provide the user with a menu and then display OS information based on their selection or quit if they enter 'q'

I've got the menu input/output loop working but I'm also required to make sure they selected a valid option and reprompt them if not.

It outputs the invalid message no matter what the user input value is.

So if the user enters 1 it will return:

Invalid input, please select an option from the menu
@{OsName=Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard}
Press Enter to continue...:

I have no background in programming so my understanding of powershell and coding is very basic and  most search results have provided examples that are beyond the scope of my knowledge!

```
function sysInfoMenu {

    param (
    [string] $Title = 'System Information'
    )

    Clear-Host

    Write-Host "=============== $Title ==============="
    "`n`n"
    Write-Host "Please select from the following options:"
    "`n"
    Write-Host "Press 1 for: OS System"
    Write-Host "Press 2 for: OS Type"
    Write-Host "Press 3 for: OS Architecture (32 or 64 bit)"
    Write-Host "Press 4 for: OS Version"
    Write-Host "Press 5 for: OS Bios Version"
    Write-Host "Press 6 for: Computer Brand"
    Write-Host "Press 7 for: Computer Name"
    Write-Host "Press 8 for: Current Domain"
    Write-Host "Press 9 for: Computer Model"
    Write-Host "Press 10 for: Current User"
    Write-Host "Press 11 for: Timezone"
    Write-Host "Press 'q' to quit."
}

do {
    sysInfoMenu
    $info = $null
    $UserInput = Read-Host "Please select an option from the menu"

        
    switch ($UserInput)
    {
      '1' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSName}
      '2' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSType}
      '3' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSArchitecture}
      '4' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSVersion}
      '5' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property BiosVersion}
      '6' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsManufacturer}
      '7' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsName}
      '8' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsDomain}
      '9' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsModel}
      '10' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsUserName}
      '11' {$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property TimeZone}
    } 
          
          
       if ($UserInput -lt 1 -gt 11 -ne 'q'){
       Write-Host "Invalid input, please select an option from the menu"
       } 
      
  Write-Host $info
  pause
       
        
}
until ($UserInput -eq 'q')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of structural problems.

- You didn't terminate your function.
- You didn't call your function.
- You keep calling Get-ComputerInfo which is slow and only needs to be done once.
- Your menu needs to be in your loop so you can clear the screen and get rid of the previous answers and/or error messages.

Here's some alternative code which I've commented to help you learn.

```
function SysInfoMenu {

    param (
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
      [string] $Title = 'System Information'
    )

#Setup:

   $ByeBye   = $False           #Set initial value.
   #Hide the Progress Bar. Remove line if not wanted.
   $ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
   $CompInfo = Get-ComputerInfo #You only need to call once.

#Main Function Code:

do {
    Clear-Host

    Write-Host "=============== $Title ==============="
    "`n`n"
    Write-Host "Please select from the following options:"
    "`n"
    Write-Host "Press  1 for: OS System"
    Write-Host "Press  2 for: OS Type"
    Write-Host "Press  3 for: OS Architecture (32 or 64 bit)"
    Write-Host "Press  4 for: OS Version"
    Write-Host "Press  5 for: OS Bios Version"
    Write-Host "Press  6 for: Computer Brand"
    Write-Host "Press  7 for: Computer Name"
    Write-Host "Press  8 for: Current Domain"
    Write-Host "Press  9 for: Computer Model"
    Write-Host "Press 10 for: Current User"
    Write-Host "Press 11 for: Timezone"
    Write-Host "Press 'q' to quit."

    $UserInput = Read-Host "Please select an option from the menu"
        
 #Note: use of Break to leave switch once match is found.
       
    switch ($UserInput) {
       '1' {$CompInfo.OSName         ;Break}
       '2' {$CompInfo.OSType         ;Break}
       '3' {$CompInfo.OSArchitecture ;Break}
       '4' {$CompInfo.OSVersion      ;Break}
       '5' {$CompInfo.BiosVersion    ;Break}
       '6' {$CompInfo.CsManufacturer ;Break}
       '7' {$CompInfo.CsName         ;Break}
       '8' {$CompInfo.CsDomain       ;Break}
       '9' {$CompInfo.CsModel        ;Break}
      '10' {$CompInfo.CsUserName     ;Break}
      '11' {$CompInfo.TimeZone       ;Break}
      'q'  {$ByeBye = $True          ;Break}
      default {"Invalid input, please select an option from the menu"}
    } #End Switch      
          
    if (-not $ByeBye) { pause }
        
  } until ($ByeBye) #Exit via $ByeBye value!

} #End Function SysInfoMenu

SysInfoMenu #Call your function
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its working as intended now!

Answer (score 0):

Your script is almost fine, you're just having some trouble with your `if` condition:

```
$UserInput -lt 1 -gt 11 -ne 'q'
```

This is how PowerShell is evaluating the statement, and why it is always entering the `if` condition. Using the word **test** as `$userInput`:

```
'test' -lt 1   # => $false
$false -gt 11  # => $false
$false -ne 'q' # => $true
```

This is how it should look, note the use of [`-and`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.2):

```
'test' -lt 1 -and 'test' -gt 11 -and 'test' -ne 'q'
```

There is an alternative you can use with the [`-notmatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) operator which allows the use of [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2).

In the example below, `$UserInput -notmatch $regex` will return `$true` at any user input that is **not** the ones we see on the `$validoptions` array (from `1` to `11` + `q`).

```
$validoptions = 1..11 + 'q'
$regex = '^{0}$' -f ($validoptions -join '$|^')
# Regex: ^1$|^2$|^3$|^4$|^5$|^6$|^7$|^8$|^9$|^10$|^11$|^q$

$waitForUSer = {
    'Press ENTER to Continue...'
    Read-Host
}

do
{
    sysInfoMenu
    $UserInput = Read-Host "Please select an option from the menu"
    
    if ($UserInput -notmatch $regex){
        Write-Warning "Invalid input, please select an option from the menu"
        & $waitForUSer
        continue # => Go to Until, skip next lines
    }

    if($UserInput -eq 'q'){
        continue # => Go to Until and end the loop
    }
   
    $info = switch ($UserInput)
    {
      '1'  { 'Option 1' }
      '2'  { 'Option 2' }
      '3'  { 'Option 3' }
      '4'  { 'Option 4' }
      '5'  { 'Option 5' }
      '6'  { 'Option 6' }
      '7'  { 'Option 7' }
      '8'  { 'Option 8' }
      '9'  { 'Option 9' }
      '10' { 'Option 10' }
      '11' { 'Option 11' }
    }
      
    $info # => Show selection
    & $waitForUSer
}
until ($UserInput -eq 'q')
```

Comment: Thanks! I've learned a lot from that